# Assetic and template inheritance

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

Is this possible to use assetic with inheritance ? With the code below I get this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_41351d9" as such route does not exist.

My app layout :

```
{# app/Resources/views/layout.html.twig 
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        'assets/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'
        'assets/js/main.js'
        output='assets/compiled/app.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {%  endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

My child layout :

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}
...
{% block javascripts %}
    {{  parent() }}

    {% javascripts
        'assets/js/jquery.owl.min.js'
        output='assets/compiled/page.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {%  endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: did you tried to suply full path for assets? like `bundles/app/js/jquery.owl.min.js` ?

Comment: I have the same problem and just found this question. Any idea how to solve this? I did exactly how OP did and getting a similar error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use inheritance with Twig, and there is nothing inherently wrong with what you are trying to do in your code.  I would try completely clearing your cache and loading the page again, and make sure all of the assets you are trying to load properly exist.

Comment: No change and assets exists (that work with a simple asset() function in twig.

Comment: Are your javascripts in bundles?  You can reference them with @BundleName notation (ex: `@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.owl.min.js`)

Comment: The problem is only with static content (in app/Resources/static/apage.html.twig), all assets are avaiable in the web folder.

Comment: I've tried myself with both js's in web folder and in bundle/resources/public/js and assetic doesn't generate the js for the parent template.

Comment: Something to add, this didn't work on an older 2.8 project but it works on a new 3.0 one. Could be one of the dependencies that is causing it or the 2.8 version.

Comment: That's weird, I mean I literally have the same sort of code but use the @BundleName notation (as described in my comment) and it works fine on 2.7.

Comment: In my case, I figured it has to be a vendor bundle. Turned out to be liipthemebundle. I've edited my answer below. @Jerome mind checking?

Comment: Looks like you figured it out and that it was something that made sense. Good job tracking it down.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not working the way we wanted it, but I discovered [named assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets)

You name all your parent template assets in the config file

```
assetic:
assets:
    jquery_and_ui:
        inputs:
            - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/jquery.js'
            - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/jquery.ui.js'
```

And then you include the `jquery_and_ui` name in all children, along with any other assets:

```
{% javascripts
    '@jquery_and_ui'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

It's obviously a hassle to do but I can't find the easy way to do this and don't understand why it doesn't generate parent template assets.

**EDIT**

Are you by any chance using LiipThemeBundle? [This](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle#assetic-integration) could solve the problem:

```
# app/config/config.yml
liip_theme:
    # ...
    assetic_integration: true
```

Comment: As long as you use @BundleName annotation you should be able to reference without named assets.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine. Extending block javascripts is ok for assets as well.

Actually such a message

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_41351d9" as
>   such route does not exist

says about outdated cache. Did you clear it? That helped me.

`php app/console cache:clear --env=dev`

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it appeared that error was caused by fact that the base file extension was .html.twig, while child file had only .twig - changing extensions of both files to .html.twig solved the problem...